# c# autorun program upon folder access, is it possible?

Tags: c#, batch-file, autorun

Is it possible to create a C#.net (or a .bat) program that will automatically run upon access of a specific folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Try and see? Any effort so far?

Comment: I honestly hope this is not possible: otherwise, this would open new horizons for writers of viruses.

Comment: This is for the purpose of securing a specific shared folder that contains sensitive info by having it password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7/8/10: Not if you don't have a background process running that checks for the folder to be opened. So no, considering you want this to behave autonomously, I'm afraid not.

Windows XP: Yes, but let's not do that. This brings security issues and the only implementation I know of is the MS32DLL virus that would do this to partition roots.

EDIT: Based on your last comment (in particular the one that elaborates the context being data security), this is the wrong approach. There are multiple ways around this (think of any third party file browser, even DOS will work) and having this feature in Windows would leave it very vulnerable to attacks. Instead, you should read into applying NTFS permissions and file encryption.